# Combine language-specific settings for multiple languages in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to enable word wrap only for specific file types, for example for `.tex` and `.txt` files. In my `settings.json`, I've added the following lines:

```
"[latex]": {
    "editor.wordWrap": "on"
},
"[plaintext]": {
    "editor.wordWrap": "on"
}
```

Is there a way to combine these two options into one to avoid duplication?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/51935

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of version 1.63, this is now possible as follows:

```
"[plaintext][latex]": {
    "editor.wordWrap": "on"
}
```

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_63#_multiple-language-specific-editor-settings

Comment: just tried this in a local settings.json file and it did not work `"[typescript][css]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },`

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I was just looking into this and an answer here would have saved me some time.

Your approach is the correct one, and is the only option other than specifying word wrap globally. To answer your question directly, there is no way to combine them. In fact, this is how language-specific settings are specified in [VS Code's default configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings).